# Как вывести по значению 2, если в базе в поле указаны 2,3,4?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

В базе artist, есть поле genres, где указаны идентификаторы в формате 2,4,6,32 направлений музыки из другой базы данных style_music. Нужно допустим выводить музыканта по стилю музыки id которого равен 2 - Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Это **очень** плохой способ связи записей.

В поле связи должен быть один Id. Почитайте про [организацию связей в БД](http://www.online-academy.ru/demo/access/urok1/teor/teor4.htm).

Сделайте таблицу связей с двумя полями - GenreId и StyleId.

Comment: Точно ты прав! Туплю! 

Слушай, но вот у меня при добавлении когда выбираются стили js формирует строку 2,3,1,7 как ее допустим разложить и записать в базу?

Comment: ну, сделайте split по ',', получите массив Id жанров. далее в зависимости от структуры базы пойдут insert'ы

Comment: Возможно, более наглядно: http://apachephpmysql.blogspot.ru/2013/03/mysql_28.html